# Replace original data with random values (Oracle)

Tags: database, oracle, random, replace, oracle19c

Into **tableA.Names** I got data:

```
83601 Thomas Levy
Adam Jonson
```

I need to replace original data with some random. I can use:

```
dbms_random.string('a',10) string.
```

and the result is:

```
OflRDIBSoN
```

How to do that the result will be like:

```
45618 ERGHNYU IULB.
```

First it should count values:

```
83601 - 5 letter
Thomas - 6 letter
Levy - 4 letter
```

and the do like
**`dbms_random.string('a',5) + dbms_random.string('a',6) + dbms_random.string('a',4)`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break down the string into the part, Replace the words with random values and combine them again as follows:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(dbms_random.string('a',LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR,'[^ ]+',1, L.LVL))), ' ') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY L.LVL)
FROM YOUR_DATA T 
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(T.STR,' ') + 1) L
GROUP BY T.STR;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-x4bLjqh)

Comment: YOUR_DATA T  => what should I put? table name? 
let say I got: select NAMES from a.someTable;

Comment: Yes, It should be table_name

Comment: perfect, works as expected

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split `names` into separate *words*, calculate their length and fetch random value based on that length.

Example shows the whole CTE, with all parts I mentioned so that you could select *everything* from it and see what's going on. The final query returns desired result.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with tablea (names) as
  2  (select '83601 Thomas Levy' from dual union all
  3   select '12345 Adam Jonson' from dual
  4  ),
```

Split names to *words*, calculate their length:

```
  5  temp as
  6    (select names,
  7       column_value rn,
  8       regexp_substr(names, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) str,
  9       length(regexp_substr(names, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value)) len
 10     from tablea cross join
 11       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                           connect by level <= regexp_count(names, ' ') + 1
 13                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
```

Finally, get random strings and aggregate them back to form the result:

```
 15  select names,
 16    listagg(case when rn = 1 then to_char(trunc(dbms_random.value(power(10, len - 1), power(10, len) - 1)))
 17                             else dbms_random.string('a', len)
 18            end, ' '
 19           ) within group (order by names, rn) result
 20  from temp
 21  group by names;

NAMES             RESULT
----------------- ----------------------------------------
12345 Adam Jonson 93154 nAhI NvrKrn
83601 Thomas Levy 42913 EOKZal LVrd

SQL>
```

Comment: when I run second command it's getting error:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: błąd liczby lub wartości
ORA-06512: przy "SYS.DBMS_RANDOM", linia 204
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s".....probably some data is wrong, but anyway it's complicated :/

Comment: As demonstrated, that piece of code works on sample data you posted. Can't tell what might be wrong; check source data (the NAMES column); can it be NULL? If so, handle it. As of code being complicated: well, write simpler one if you know how, no problem.

Comment: yes it was null